# TeamCity - Update build number of currently running build

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, teamcity

I have a build step which is updating values used in my build number. My build number is in a format like 1.0.0-1, where the final 1 is the build counter and the others are environment variables, like `env.major.version`, etc.

This step updates them fine, in that other steps in the build use the new values, and the values are updated when I view the build config settings, but the number of that build itself isn't changed.

So for example, my latest build is 1.0.0-6. I am running a new build which updates the version to 1.0.1 and resets the build counter to 1. But this build will have a number 1.0.0-7 instead of 1.0.1-1, and only on the next build will it use the latest values.

Is there a way to change the build number of the build that is currently running? I am using the rest api to set my version environment variables and set the `buildNumberCounter`, and then using `##teamcity[setParameter ...]##` as well so that the other build steps get the latest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer for this on the [TeamCity forum](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000397739-Update-build-number-of-currently-running-build?page=1#community_comment_360000087999)

You can use `##teamcity[buildNumber '1.0.1-1']##` and the current build's number will be updated